# Indexing dynamic loading page

Tags: indexing, web-crawler

Does Google index dynamic loading page?

**For example**

*index.html*

```
<div id="dynamic_message"></div>
```

*index.html after few seconds*

```
<div id="dynamic_message">Hello Google, do you see me?</div>
```

Will Google index div#dynamic_message? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a general answer is ok for you or if you even intended to be more general: In general crawlers do not execute javascript. I cannot tell for sure if Google does it (they do read Flash), but if this is rather a question of developing your website than exactly about Google’s capabilities, then I would recommend you not to use Javascript for content that should be crawled (as most crawlers will not load the content).